# Special coordinates on $S^n$.

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I vaguely remember some special kind of coordinates on the sphere $\mathbb S^n$ as a Riemannian manifold, but I have forgotten their name: They are defined by choosing a great $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ and considering the geodesic from every point of it, that travels in the direction orthogonal to the great $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. The distance of a point on this geodesic to the $\mathbb S^{n-1}$ defines the first entry of the coordinate tuple. The other entries are given by choosing a local coordinate system, that describes the position of a point on the great $S^{n-1}$. In other words: The first coordinate entry is the distance to the great $S^{n-1}$ and the other entries are the coordinates on the $S^{n-1}$ where the minimizing geodesic meets $S^{n-1}$.

I must admit, that I only vaguely remember these coordinates and might be slightly mistaken about their definition. The metric of $\mathbb S^n$ at least should be in the form $dt^2+ g(t)(x)$ where $t$ is the geodesic distance to $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. I don't mean polar coordinates, because their you measure the distance to a point and not to a great $S^{n-1}$.

There should be such coordinates at least in a neighborhood of every point on the $\mathbb S^{n-1}$. I now would like to know, what the name of these coordinates is and (if you can tell me) also what the metric $g(t)$ is in these coordinates. I would appreciate every answer to this question.

Comment: Are you studying differential geometry? If so, you should work this out yourself. It's best to view the sphere as a submanifold of Euclidean space, do it first for $n = 1$, and then for $n = 2$. For these cases, you can consult books such as O'Neill or Do Carmo's book on curves and surfaces.

Comment: The coordinates you describe on sphere are the standard spherical coordinates up to shift by $\tfrac\pi2$.
In dimension 2, the construction you describe gives so called "semigeodesic coordinates";
they can be constructed locally on any surface. 

Comment: Such coordinates are also sometimes called _Gauss normal coordinates_.